# Binary searching in tree

Tags: c

I need to create this tree:
[the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvAkN.png)

I need to implement a function that takes the tree's node (root), a number, and returns how many times the binary representation of the number occurs in the tree.

For example:
9(1001) occurs 4 times

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode* leftNode;
    struct TreeNode* rightNode;
};

void strrev(char * arr, int start, int end) {
    char temp;
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }
    temp = * (arr + start);
    *(arr + start) = * (arr + end);
    *(arr + end) = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
    strrev(arr, start, end);
}

char * itoa(int number, char * arr, int base) {
    int i = 0, r, negative = 0;
    if (number == 0) {
        arr[i] = '0';
        arr[i + 1] = '\0';
        return arr;
    }
    if (number < 0 && base == 10) {
        number *= -1;
        negative = 1;
    }
    while (number != 0) {
        r = number % base;
        arr[i] = (r > 9) ? (r - 10) + 'a' : r + '0';
        i++;
        number /= base;
    }
    if (negative) {
        arr[i] = '-';
        i++;
    }
    strrev(arr, 0, i - 1);
    arr[i] = '\0';
    return arr;
}

int count_occurrences(struct TreeNode* root, int number) {
    int count = 0;
    char binary[33];
    itoa(number, binary, 2);
    int length = strlen(binary);

    struct TreeNode* current = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (binary[i] == '0') {
            if (current->leftNode != NULL) {
                current = current->leftNode;
            } else {
                return count;
            }
        } else {
            if (current->rightNode != NULL) {
                current = current->rightNode;
            } else {
                return count;
            }
        }
        if (current->val == number) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

struct TreeNode* createNode(int value) {
    struct TreeNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    newNode->val = value;
    newNode->leftNode = NULL;
    newNode->rightNode = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct TreeNode* insertLeftNode(struct TreeNode* rootNode, int value) {
    rootNode->leftNode = createNode(value);
    return rootNode->leftNode;
}

struct TreeNode* insertRightNode(struct TreeNode* rootNode, int value) {
    rootNode->rightNode = createNode(value);
    return rootNode->rightNode;
}

int main() {
    struct TreeNode* rootNode = createNode(1);
    insertLeftNode(rootNode, 1);
    insertRightNode(rootNode, 0);
    insertLeftNode(rootNode->leftNode, 0);
    insertRightNode(rootNode->leftNode, 1);
    insertLeftNode(rootNode->rightNode, 0);
    insertRightNode(rootNode->rightNode, 0);
    insertLeftNode(rootNode->leftNode->leftNode, 0);
    insertRightNode(rootNode->leftNode->leftNode, 0);
    insertLeftNode(rootNode->rightNode->rightNode, 0);
    insertRightNode(rootNode->rightNode->rightNode, 0);    
    printf("\n%d", count_occurrences(rootNode, 9));
}
```

I am using itoa(), but for some reasons it doesn't return nothing.
Itoa gave compiler warning so i copied it from internet.
Also I think i am not correctly creating the tree.

Comment: Can that ```itao()``` not be replaced with a ```sprintf / snprintf```?

Comment: ```temp = * (arr + start);``` can be written as ```temp = arr[start];``` ---> It's more readable.

Comment: *"I am using itoa(), but for some reasons it doesn't return nothing"* ----> How would it when you're ignoring its return value?

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings

Comment: When i copied the itoa function it stopped giving warnings

Comment: @Haris , the problem is in count_occurrences()

Comment: Hint: you can use bit masking: `(number & (1 << treelevel)) ^ nodeval == 0`.